# headers already sent by in index function and normal function

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function index()
{
$data['home'] = $this->load->view('home', $data, true); // load view
}

public function register_user(){

$data['home'] = $this->load->view('home', $data, true); // load view
}
```

in my home.php (view) there is a link to click to home/register_user and I got an error headers already sent error. I think I know why because my index of home controller also load the view. But if I removed the index's load view, then my home page is broken, because unregistered user will land first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header which is already sent using

```
void header_remove ([ string $name ] )
```

https://www.php.net/header_remove